# cannot complete this action 0x80004005

Tags: sharepoint-2010

After saving a working site as a template, and then creating a new site based on this templete I get the following error when deleteing an item from a list via the browser

cannot complete this action 0x80004005

Looking at the ULS log all I seem to get is

Cannot complete this action.  Please try again.0x80004005

Interestingly, if I save the list as a termplate and then create a list from that template, I don't get the error

Any ideas?

Comment: That number is the E_FAIL error code which is basically the default error code for COM methods. You will need to work out which object and what method call was last called.

Comment: well I was also getting LockManager: A Web Lock should have been taken here.

Which seems to relate to cascade deletes, so after some investigation one of the related lists had had its cascade delete behavior turned off.  Turned it back on all working.

Hope that helps someone.